# Is there any scriptural support for Ramakrishna's avatarhood?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, ramakrishna

Sri Ramakrishna mission and the devotees claim that Sri Ramakrishna was an Avatar. Even Sri Ramakrishna declared that he was an Avatar. However, Puranas mentioned only 10 avatars of Vishnu. The only Vishnu avatar yet to come is the Kalki.

Even Gaudiya Vaishnavas, who claim Lord Chaitanya was an Avatar of Vishnu, show passages from Srimad Bhagavatam supporting the lofty claim.

What scriptural support is there in favour of the declaration of the Ramakrishna Mission?

Comment: Maybe/the/every "enlighted one" is considered to be a "avtar" or "incarnation" or part of a perticular "god"?

Comment: @Proxy no, only people born enlightened are considered avatar. Rest are just enlightened people

Comment: @MrGreenGold when God incarnates he is called avatar.

Comment: @DarkKnight correct. I was only talking as per Advaita.

Comment: "Puranas mentioned only 10 avatars of Vishnu" -- these r the main avtaras but not only avtaras...other famous set is 24 avtaras...but Puranas mention even more avatars...so u can remove this line..

Comment: @YDS - he need not remove it. others also have same doubt cos they only hear 10 avatars. it is better to publish both doubt and answer (after we get the answer). in cases where we don't have answer yet, then we can delay publishing the doubt, because it can mislead people.

Comment: The mention of Avatars or Incarnations does not appear in the vedas. It is only in the Puranas that the concept first appears. The arguments as to Ramakrishna being an Incarnation are argued in "Sri Ramakrishna: The Great Master" The author, Swami Saradananda also goes into detail as to the kinds and degrees of free souls and Isvarkoti, Adikarika- Purushas, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no scriptural support for this. Atleast not in any ancient canonical scriptures.

This, however finds mention in the literature of Ramakrishna Mission exclusively, in the works of acharyas and swami's of Ramakrishna Order.

I think, it's most explicitly given in the biography book - '[SRI RAMAKRISHNA
THE GREAT MASTER](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/sriramakrishna_thegreatmaster/srkgrtmaster.htm)' (4th Edition) *BY SWAMI SARADANANDA*

Consider these excerpts.

1. Swami Vivekananda himself told of his master's avatarahood.

> [HINDU RELIGION AND SRI RAMAKRISHNA](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/sriramakrishna_thegreatmaster/srkgrtmaster_files/hindusrk.html)
>
> **The One born as Rama of incomparable greatness** in all the three worlds, the very life of Janaka’s daughter; who, though himself beyond
> the world lo, did not give up doing good to it; the current of whose
> love flowed ever unchecked down even to a Chandala; and whose body of
> supreme knowledge was enveloped by devotion in the form of Sita; **the
> One born as Krishna,** who sang the song (the Gita) sweet and
> tranquil, yet deep as the roar of a lion, suppressing the great
> cataclysmic tumult raised in the battlefield and destroying the innate
> profound darkness of ignorance— **that ever-renowned divine
> personality is now born as Ramakrishna.**<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1. The above is a translation of two Sanskrit stanzas composed by Swami Vivekananda.—Tr.</sup>

Further, at the end of the Book.

2. In his horoscope prediction, he's called Narayana's incarnation.

> [THE HOROSCOPE OF SRI RAMAKRISHNA](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/sriramakrishna_thegreatmaster/srkgrtmaster_files/Sri%20Ramakrishna%20-%20The%20Great%20Master-77.html)
>
> *By Narayanachandra Jyotirbhushana*
>
> The result of this natal arrangement of the planets is, according to
> Bhrigu Samhita, that the man becomes the head of a religious movement,
> virtuous, highly honoured, always engaged in doing virtuous deeds; he
> lives in a temple, and gets a large following of disciples; **he is
> called a great man by all, and is born of the spirit of Lord Narayana;
> he is worshipped by all.**

**In any case, notwithstanding these sources, no canonical Pauranika text or others refers Sri Ramakrishna, let alone any avatarahood of his.**